Correcting a UID String to Match a Given Pattern Using Character Substitution
uid = "lz09ll"
pattern = r"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$"
corrected_uid = correct_uid(uid, pattern)
print("Corrected UID:", corrected_uid)  # Expected Output: "lz0911"

Given a UID string and a regex pattern, I want to check each position in the UID against the regex. If a position in the UID is supposed to be a digit (per the regex) but has a letter instead, I want to substitute the letter with the correct digit based on a dictionary of character mappings. Similarly, if a letter is expected but there's a digit, I want to replace it.
I have a dictionary char_to_digit and digit_to_char, to swap based on position and regex.
I've tried iterating over each character in uid based on pattern, checking for mismatches and applying substitutions, but the logic doesn't handle positions correctly and sometimes results in None due to mismatches.

Since your input appears to be fixed width, why not just iterate over the first two chars in each string with digit_to_char and the latter four chars with char_to_digit? Not sure why you'd need regex for this.

I think this is what you want:
import re

char_to_digit = {'l': '1', 'I': '1', 'o': '0', 'O': '0', 'S': '5', 's': '5', 'Z': '2', 'z': '2', 'E': '3', 'B': '8',
                 'G': '6', 'b': '6', 'Q': '0', 'A': '4', 'T': '7', 'F': '7'}
digit_to_char = {'0': 'O', '1': 'I', '5': 'S', '2': 'Z', '3': 'E', '8': 'B', '6': 'G', '4': 'A', '7': 'T'}


def change(mo):
    result = ''
    for i in range(1, len(mo.groups()) + 1):
        if i in (1, 2) and mo[i].isdigit():
            result += str(digit_to_char.get(mo[i] if i == 2 else '0', mo[i]))
        elif i > 2 and mo[i].isalpha():
            result += str(char_to_digit.get(mo[i], mo[i]))
        else:
            result += mo[i]
    return result

print("Corrected UID:", re.sub(r'^(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)$', change, "lz09ll"))  # Output: "lz0911"
print("Corrected UID:", re.sub(r'^(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)$', change, "8z09ll"))  # Output: "Oz0911"
print("Corrected UID:", re.sub(r'^(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)$', change, "lz09Gb"))  # Output: "lz0966"


umm, not really
here is my dict
char_to_digit = {
'l': '1', 'I': '1', 'o': '0', 'O': '0', 'S': '5', 's': '5', 'Z': '2',
'z': '2', 'E': '3', 'B': '8', 'G': '6', 'b': '6', 'Q': '0', 'A': '4',
'T': '7', 'F': '7'
}
digit_to_char = {
'0': 'O', '1': 'I', '5': 'S', '2': 'Z', '3': 'E', '8': 'B', '6': 'G', '4': 'A', '7': 'T'
}
i need to swap it from appropriate dict based on pattern   pattern = r"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$"
if my first input is not letter say 0(zero), then it should go to digit_to_char and 0 should become o

@Syed_Furqhan007 I edited my answer to fit your dicts and logic about first input. How about now?

whats mo by the way. and i wanna correct the input based on a regular expression pattern

mo is short for matched object. In your logic, your reg pattern should be used for checking at last, not at the beginning.  @Syed_Furqhan007

hey, just a small help by the way, can i construct a list based on regular expression
like if my regex is --> ^[0-9]/a-z/[a-zA-Z]{4}$
then i want my list to be --> [0, '/', a, '/', a, a, a, a]
so if i know the index and the type of char present, then i will convert my input into a list and check in accordance to the index, if the index at list from regex has char, but my input is digit then i will swap
i have checked something like  -



a = "001hello"
b = list(a)
b[0].isdigit()
True
b[5].isdigit()
False



This way i could accomidate any pattern with any input

@Syed_Furqhan007 Sure you can. But I don't get what is your question exactly..

Here is the question -
i am trying to extract a unique ID from an image, but sometimes the image is not clear and it return wrong characters, to tackle so i observed there is pattern while it picks wrong and put it in dict,
the unique ID can have any format (validated over the regex, i have a config file that hold the regex), now i need to check in case the uid does not match the regex, i need to swap values to accomidate the actual result.
can you help me build one list as such, given any regex, if the position is letter then put a, if it is digit put 0, if special char put as it is

@Syed_Furqhan007 you mean this? print((lambda s: ['a' if i.isalpha() else (0 if i.isdigit() else i) for i in str(s)])('asd_001')) change asd_001 to your input string.

i deteremine the change based on regular expression and the corresponding position of the input (while being in context with the input)
